# Store option from drop down menu into database

Tags: php, html, forms

I have the following form field in my html code:

```
<select class="secret_question">
                     <option value ="1">The name of the city where you were born</option>
                     <option value ="2">The name of your first pet</option>
                     <option value ="3">What is your mother's maiden name</option>
                  </select>
```

Question: How to I store the selected option into the database. I have been able to store normal fields  like a name, email-id into a database with the following code :

```
$firstname = $_REQUEST['firstname'];
    $lastname = $_REQUEST['lastname'];
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO users (firstname,lastname) VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname')");
```

I have tried the same technique for the select list but it gives me the `"undefined index"` error

Comment: Name your `<select>` like `<select class="secret_question" name="secret_question">` then use `$secret_question = $_REQUEST['secret_question'];` which seems to be the case here. Then use that to put in your DB. You didn't post your full form, so it's hard to tell 100% - the other probable reason would be to use `VALUES ('" . $firstname . "', '" . $lastname . "')` which is also a safer method to use.

Comment: I now feel stupid. thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome, just glad I could help. I posted something below that may be useful, cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get an `undefined index` error if a form element is not "**named**".

You need to name your `<select>` like the following:

```
<select class="secret_question" name="secret_question">
```

then use `$secret_question = $_REQUEST['secret_question'];`

Such as the following:

```
$firstname = $_REQUEST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_REQUEST['lastname'];
$secret_question = $_REQUEST['secret_question'];
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO users (firstname,lastname,secret_question) 
VALUES ('" . $firstname . "', '" . $lastname . "', '" . $secret_question . "')");
```

While naming your DB column `secret_question`

Using the following convention is safer:

`'" . $firstname . "'` instead of `'$firstname'`

However, you may want to use an input field instead of a `<select>` because people may be typing in an answer themselves, this depending on how your setup is.